# In AEM 6.2, Custom Comment component is not working on publish instance but working good on Author instance

Tags: java, aem

We recently upgraded from AEM 6.0 to 6.2, On 6.0 custom comment component was working good on both instance (Author & publisher). But after upgrade,
it is working good on author instanec but not on publish instance.

Below is the error code which it is throwing:

```
05.04.2017 07:46:34.070 *ERROR* [10.98.144.143 [1491378393951] POST /content/vknow/en/news/2015/20151210-flood-india/jcr:content/reviews.social.json HTTP/1.1] com.adobe.cq.social.scf.core.operations.AbstractSocialOperation Error performing operation:
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.adobe.cq.social.commons.comments.api.AbstractComment.<init>(AbstractComment.java:240)
    at com.adobe.cq.social.review.client.api.AbstractReview.<init>(AbstractReview.java:85)
    at com.adobe.cq.social.review.client.api.AbstractReview.<init>(AbstractReview.java:71)
    at com.adobe.cq.social.review.client.impl.ReviewSocialComponentImpl.<init>(ReviewSocialComponentImpl.java:33)
    at com.adobe.cq.social.review.client.api.ReviewSocialComponentFactory.getSocialComponent(ReviewSocialComponentFactory.java:51)
    at com.adobe.cq.social.review.client.endpoints.impl.ReviewOperationsService.getSocialComponentForResource(ReviewOperationsService.java:637)
    at com.adobe.cq.social.review.client.endpoints.impl.ReviewOperationsService.getSocialComponentForResource(ReviewOperationsService.java:75)
    at com.adobe.cq.social.commons.comments.endpoints.AbstractCommentOperationService.create(AbstractCommentOperationService.java:843)
    at com.adobe.cq.social.commons.comments.endpoints.AbstractCommentOperationService.create(AbstractCommentOperationService.java:915)
    at com.adobe.cq.social.review.client.endpoints.impl.ReviewOperationsService.create(ReviewOperationsService.java:127)
    at com.adobe.cq.social.review.client.endpoints.impl.ReviewPostOperation.performOperation(ReviewPostOperation.java:81)
    at com.adobe.cq.social.commons.comments.endpoints.AbstractCommentOperation.performOperation(AbstractCommentOperation.java:137)
    at com.adobe.cq.social.scf.core.operations.AbstractSocialOperation.run(AbstractSocialOperation.java:82)
    at org.apache.sling.servlets.post.impl.SlingPostServlet.doPost(SlingPostServlet.java:202)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet.mayService(SlingAllMethodsServlet.java:149)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:345)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:376)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:546)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:44)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilterWithErrorHandling(WCMDebugFilter.java:187)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:154)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:236)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDeveloperModeFilter.doFilter(WCMDeveloperModeFilter.java:114)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:282)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.dispatchRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:322)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.SlingRequestDispatcher.dispatch(SlingRequestDispatcher.java:211)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.SlingRequestDispatcher.include(SlingRequestDispatcher.java:104)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter$ForwardRequestDispatcher.include(WCMComponentFilter.java:503)
    at com.adobe.cq.social.ugcbase.security.impl.SaferSlingPostServlet.doPost(SaferSlingPostServlet.java:105)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet.mayService(SlingAllMethodsServlet.java:149)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:345)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:376)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:546)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:44)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilterWithErrorHandling(WCMDebugFilter.java:187)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:154)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.filterRootInclude(WCMComponentFilter.java:362)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:177)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDeveloperModeFilter.doFilter(WCMDeveloperModeFilter.java:114)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:282)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.dispatchRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:322)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.SlingRequestDispatcher.dispatch(SlingRequestDispatcher.java:211)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.SlingRequestDispatcher.include(SlingRequestDispatcher.java:104)
    at com.adobe.cq.social.ugcbase.security.impl.SaferSlingPostServlet.include(SaferSlingPostServlet.java:211)
    at com.adobe.cq.social.ugcbase.security.impl.SaferSlingPostServlet.doFilter(SaferSlingPostServlet.java:124)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.assetlinkshare.AdhocAssetShareAuthHandler.doFilter(AdhocAssetShareAuthHandler.java:381)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.servlet.ActivityRecordHandler.doFilter(ActivityRecordHandler.java:155)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:73)
    at com.adobe.granite.requests.logging.impl.RequestLoggerImpl.doFilter(RequestLoggerImpl.java:127)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.adobe.granite.csrf.impl.CSRFFilter.doFilter(CSRFFilter.java:220)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ContentDispositionFilter.doFilter(ContentDispositionFilter.java:181)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.doFilter(AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.java:292)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter.doFilter(TimeWarpFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:248)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.symantec.syminfo.core.impl.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:50)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.cognifide.slice.core.internal.filter.ContextRequestFilter.doFilter(ContextRequestFilter.java:90)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.analytics.provisioning.impl.UserAuthenticationRequestFilter.doFilter(UserAuthenticationRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.doFilter(RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.java:95)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.adobe.cq.social.commons.cors.CORSAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(CORSAuthenticationFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet.doFilter(FormsHandlingServlet.java:285)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.adobe.granite.optout.impl.OptOutFilter.doFilter(OptOutFilter.java:74)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter.doFilter(WCMRequestFilter.java:90)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.adobe.cq.mcm.campaign.servlets.CampaignCopyTracker.doFilter(CampaignCopyTracker.java:100)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter.doFilter(RewriterFilter.java:83)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:77)
    at com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:56)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.adobe.granite.rest.impl.servlet.ApiResourceFilter.doFilter(ApiResourceFilter.java:67)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:129)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.bgservlets.impl.BackgroundServletStarterFilter.doFilter(BackgroundServletStarterFilter.java:169)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.adobe.granite.resourceresolverhelper.impl.ResourceResolverHelperImpl.doFilter(ResourceResolverHelperImpl.java:84)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.doProcessRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:151)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingMainServlet.service(SlingMainServlet.java:216)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:79)
    at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:308)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
    at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:89)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
    at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:290)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
    at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:129)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
    at org.apache.sling.featureflags.impl.FeatureManager.doFilter(FeatureManager.java:116)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:124)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:61)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 2):

Issue has been resolved.In 6.2,we need to create system user and provide this user mapping to all subservices (Apache sling User mapper in OSGI). Admin user has deprecated from 6.1.Issue was related to permission (Read permission to /libs folder for system user)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code at the line where the `NullPointerException` is thrown (`AbstractComment.java:240`) it looks to me as if the `CommentSocialComponentListProvider` service is missing on your publisher:

`this.replies = listProvider.getCommentSocialComponentList(this, repliesListInfo, clientUtils);`

`listProvider` seems to be `null` on your publisher.

Check if the `com.adobe.cq.social.cq-social-commons` bundle is installed and if the `CommentSocialComponentListProvider` service is running.

Comment: yes i checked "com.adobe.cq.social.cq-social-commons" bundle is in active state,version is 1.6.91,also CommentSocialComponentListProvider service is running

Comment: Also we used browser developer tool to debug and in console tab it is showing error for post call:"http:hostname:port/content/xyz.html/jcr:content/reviews.social.json"      500 server error for granite.js(at line 239)